# Android button not working on click login

Tags: android

This is my code for login page but problem is that login button not working.
When I leave boxes empty the button works and give message enter valid email and password but when I fill boxes and clicked on the button, nothing happening.
Please help me.

```
   jlet1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.let1);
    jlet2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.let2);
    jlb1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.lb1);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);

    jlb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            email = jlet1.getText().toString();
            pwd = jlet2.getText().toString();
            if (email.equals("") || pwd.equals("")) {
                builder.setTitle("Oops wrong turn");
                displayAlert("Enter a valid Email and Password");
            }
            else{
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                        if (code.equals("login_failed")){
                            builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                            displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                        }
                        else{
                            Intent in= new Intent(login.this,welcome.class);
                            Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            in.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(in);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "Error Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("email_id",email);
                    params.put("password",pwd);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            singleton.getInstance(login.this).addRequest(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
public void displayAlert(String message){
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            jlet1.setText("");
            jlet2.setText("");
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

my logcat is showing this :

```
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.rawat.loginapp.login$1$1.onResponse(login.java:61)
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.rawat.loginapp.login$1$1.onResponse(login.java:57)
03-29 16:29:46.265 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5437)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-29 16:29:46.266 6804-6804/com.rawat.loginapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-29 16:29:46.382 1324-1388/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Message: 300

        <?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die('connection error');
$db=mysql_select_db('newdb')or die('db error');

    $email_id=$_POST["email_id"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email_id='".$email_id."' AND password='".$password."'";
    $chk=mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $response=array();
if(mysql_num_rows($chk)>0){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($chk);
    $name=$row[0];
    $code="login_success";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"name"=>$name));
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
    $code="login_failed";
    $message="User not found... please try again";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode($response);
}
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Check LogCat for Volley Errors. `onErrorResponse()` does not necessarily catch ALL errors related to Volley and networking, so you might be missing a relevant error in your logs.

Comment: you might be getting JSONException where you are only printing log in catch blog

Comment: @Deepak have you solved it

Comment: no @JanardhanR I edited my question with logcat. Please help.

Comment: Can you add json response in your question? There is error in JSONParsing

Comment: problem with your response as i told earlier JSONException you are getting hence please post response

Comment: you are getting html tag i think as response for some values

Comment: yes I am using PHP code for this... I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
 try {
JSONObject mainJsonObject =new JSONOnject(response); // this is main reason for exception.
 //change below logic as per your json getting as string response
 JSONArray jsonArray=mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("name");
  JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                    if (code.equals("login_failed")){
                        builder.setTitle("Login Error");
                        displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent in= new Intent(login.this,welcome.class);
                        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("name",jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        in.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(in);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: @DeepakRawat Here is a solution. I mentioned your mistake in the code with comment.

Comment: @DeepakRawat post your json response, You are getting @ onResponse() method.
I will post solution once you give json response

Comment: It is showing Value name of type java.lang.String cannot be converted into jsonarray

Comment: Please provide me response string value.

Comment: I didn't understand, what you saying please help.